# Terraform enterprise workspace folder structure and state files

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

We have Terraform enterprise up and running for our production setup and using AWS as our service provider.

- Automated our terraform run with GitHub, ie configured VCS provider. With four folders pointing to three different workspaces, let's call them [ `workspace_1, workspace_2, workspace_3` ]
- Due to org policy we merged all our workspaces into `workspace_1`

  - Deleted all resources from `workspace_2` and `workspace_3`
  - Created those resources in `workspace_1`
- But we want to maintain the previous structure and plan to create resources by changing the folder structure like below :

[image]

Below is the sample folder structure , we will be having:

```
|--workspace_1
|   |--workspace_2
|      |----module_A
|      |----module_B
|      |----main.tf
|      |----variable.tf
|   |---module_b
|      |----module_C
|      |----module_D
|      |----main.tf
|      |----variable.tf
|   |--main.tf
|.  |--variable.tf
```

Question :

- Is this a proper approach that we can follow, does it mess up with state files if we go this way when the number of resources increase?

Looking for best practices or approaches from terraform experts here in this community.

Answer (score 0):

Changing folder structure each time will have its own caveats, like cloud-provider configs needs to be placed and also approach seems to be error prone.
So conclusion is always have a single "Terrform Working Directory" path.